# What format should I format this flash drive as?

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive

I want to switch from using crouton to using GalliumOS on my Chromebook.  This means that I need to back up my stuff to an external drive.  I want to use a flash drive for this purpose.

However, when I try to copy my files to it, I run into a problem.  A lot of my files have a \ in their filename, due to a (probably stupid) system that I use.  This is incompatible with both FAT32 and exFAT filesystems, so I want to format one of my flash drives as something else.

What filesystem should I use to do this that would allow for almost any character in the filename?

Answer (score 1):

NTFS can handle spaces. Alternatively, easier said then done, but EXT4 is typically used by Linux based OS's - so you may want to use that if you need a filesystem that handles spaces - Windows support for that fs is not great though.

Have you considered compressing the files into a single archive and storing them on a regular FAT filesystem that can be read by anything?

Comment: I had not considered compressing them into an archive.  I think that would probably be easier and safer than trying to format the drive.  I will try that.  Thank you!